# Conditional statements importing JSON to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory which imports JSON to SQL Azure. This works fine, except some JSON files have multiple structures.

[image]

It's fine if every line was in the file is the same. I can take two runs at the files in the data lake gen 2. I don't mind ignoring the lines with rc and then having another pipeline which ignore rows with marketDefinition and just processes the others getting both into seperate tables.

Not sure what the best solution here is.

Comment: Just for now, Data factory doesn't works well for multiple files which have different schema.

Comment: Is it possible to use the pre script option to write OPENJSON query to filter the data and exclude certain rows with different schema on the first pass?

Comment: Hi @cathalobrien, No, the pre script is the operation directly to SQL database, even you pass the source file path to the script, it still won't filter the source dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Just for now, Data factory doesn't works well for multiple files which have different schema.

The pre script is the operation directly to SQL database, even you pass the source file path to the script, it still won't filter the source dataset. It's an independent command.

So I'm afraid to say there isn't a best solution for your scenario.